# Representing hierarchical data (C++)

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, class

Say we have 2 Classes: Account and Contact like this:

```
class Account {
    string Id;
    string Name;
}

class Contact {
    string Id;
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
}
```

An account can contain many contacts. This data is managed in a class "DataManager" which acts as the repository for the rest of the program. There are 2 main requirements:

- For an Account, I need to retrieve a list of its Contacts
- For a given accountId or contactId I need to retrieve the respective Account/Contact. The retrievement of a contact should work, even if I don't know which Account the contact is assigned to. Like this

  Contact c = dataManager.GetContact(contId);

I discussed with a colleague the following 2 options to implement the Account-Contact relation in C++:

**Option 1: Store hierarchically**
... the Account class would contain a map of contacts. Key of that map would be the ContactId. The DataManager would store a map of accounts:

```
class DataManager {
    Account& GetAccount(string accountId);
    Contact& GetContact(string contactId);

    map<string, Account> accounts;
}
class Account {
    map<string, Contact> contacts;

    Contact& GetContact(string contactId);
    list<reference_wrapper<Contact>> GetContacts();
}
```

Problem: The implementation of DataManager:: GetContact would need to iterate over all account's contacts. As an alternative, I could store a map of contactId -> accountId in the DataManager to quickly dereference the account that contains the required contact.

**Option 2: "Flat" storage"**
In this solution, the objects are all stored in the DataManager. The account class only stores the *Id's* of its contacts.

```
class DataManager {
    map<string, Account> accounts;
    map<string, Contact> contacts;

    Account& GetAccount(string accountId);
    Contact& GetContact(string contactId);
}
class Account {
    map<string, string> contactIds;
    list<string> GetContactIds();
}
```

Problem: To get a list of all contacts of an account, the calling code (-> in real: some code in the DataManager) needs to iterate over the list of contactIds retrieved by the Account object and collect the respective contact objects from the DataManager.

**Option 2.1 Reference wrapper**
What about containers using reference_wrapper instead of string contactId? (as suggested by @Caleth)

**What to do?**
Which of these options seems more legit to you - or do you suggest a different solution?

Comment: What about containers using `reference_wrapper<Contact>` instead of `string` contactId?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that design:

```
class DataManager {
  map<string, Account> accounts;
  map<string, Contact*> contacts;
  Account& GetAccount(string accountId);
  Contact& GetContact(string contactId);
}
class Account {
  map<string, Contact*> contacts;
  list<Contact*> GetContactIds();
}
```

So, you can access contacts of an Account directly.

**Note:** It is better to use [reference wrappers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) as @Caleth commented or [shared pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of raw Contact pointers.